# JMS File Store tuning

Tags: file, jms, weblogic, store

We are using Weblogic JMS as the JMS provider for our application. We use file store as the persistent store. Is there any mechanism to condfigure the file store size so that after the file has reached the specified size, a new file is generated. Right now I have seen that all the messages till today are persisted into one single file. I think it will affect the IO operation to read/write messages as the size increase. Has anyone come across this situation and what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://e-docs.bea.com/wls/docs81/ConsoleHelp/domain_jmsfilestore_config.html) are the details about WebLogic JMS file store tuning.

Maybe [this info](http://e-docs.bea.com/wls/docs103/jms/uoo.html) about unit-of-order processing will be helpful as well.

I can't see anything about file size, but perhaps the message paging info will be helpful.

When I've used JMS with persistent messaging, I haven't had a problem with file size.  Once a message is transacted, what happens to its entry in the file?  Shouldn't it be removed or marked as acknowledged?  Surely the file size doesn't grow without bound.